# How can I safely move /lib to a mounted partition

Tags: debian

I have made my root partition a long time ago and since I have var, home and usr in different logical volumes I made it quite small. Unfortunately /lib has grown quite a bit and my root partition is now full. I want to move /lib to a new lvm which I made and I've done the whole copying and all, but now I want to mount /dev/mapper/MySystem-lib /lib and also delete the original /lib in the root partition. I've already one managed to get myself stranded by moving /lib to /lib.old.

My question is two fold. If I put the mount in /etc/fstab and actually delete /lib on the root partition, will everything work? Since from my unfortunate mistake with the move, I've found out stuff like mount doesn't work without lib.

And second how to I get to the point where I have deleted /lib and mounted /dev/mapper/MySystem-lib in it's place?

Edit: I solve the most pressing problem (needing to upgrade with root full) by moving opt instead of lib. To respond to the question in the comments I'm adding the output of:

sudo lsblk -o +fstype

```
    NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT FSTYPE
sdb              8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
`-sdb1           8:17   0 916.6G  0 part            ext2
sda              8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk            ddf_raid_member
|-sda1           8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot      ext2
|-sda2           8:2    0     1K  0 part
`-sda5           8:5    0   1.8T  0 part            LVM2_member
  |-Oak-root   254:0    0   332M  0 lvm  /          ext4
  |-Oak-swap_1 254:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]     swap
  |-Oak-usr    254:2    0   8.4G  0 lvm  /usr       ext4
  |-Oak-var    254:3    0   2.8G  0 lvm  /var       ext4
  |-Oak-tmp    254:4    0   380M  0 lvm  /tmp       ext4
  |-Oak-home   254:5    0   1.2T  0 lvm  /home      ext4
  |-Oak-lib    254:6    0   400G  0 lvm             ext4
  `-Oak-opt    254:7    0   100G  0 lvm  /opt       ext4
sr0             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

sudo vgs

```
 VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  Oak    1   8   0 wz--n- 1.82t 134.97g
```

sudo lvs

```
 LV     VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home   Oak  -wi-ao----   1.17t
  lib    Oak  -wi-a----- 400.00g
  opt    Oak  -wi-ao---- 100.00g
  root   Oak  -wi-ao---- 332.00m
  swap_1 Oak  -wi-ao----  15.93g
  tmp    Oak  -wi-ao---- 380.00m
  usr    Oak  -wi-ao----   8.38g
  var    Oak  -wi-ao----   2.79g
```

Also while I understand (and sort of assumed you couldn't move /lib to a different partition after cutting my branch from under myself a few times by moving it), it would be great if someone with actual understanding of how the dynamically linked libraries operate and how the boot process works could write an answer why trying this is not really sensible.

Comment: `/lib` must be on the root filesystem, since it usually contains the dynamic linker/loader and `glibc`. Essentially all executables will depend on those two. If your move them away from your root filesystem, you would have to heavily customize your initramfs to mount it together with the root filesystem, or **everything** will stop working. But you mentioned LVM. If your root filesystem is on LVM, you can probably *enlarge* it very easily. Please edit your question to add the outputs of `lsblk -o +fstype`, `sudo vgs` and `sudo lvs` to it.

Comment: @telcoM I did end up just expanding / to 30Gb. I have to say I didn't realize that was a possibility on a root partition. Though I suppose it should be obvious that lvm's don't have to be contiguous. It's worth noting that I couldn't manage to expand it to 100Gb since I ran out of reserved gdb blocks. I considered trying to do the resize2fs off line, but in the end 30Gb is more than enough hopefully and that was resizable online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you already solved your disk space issue by expanding the root filesystem. But here's a more detailed explanation anyway...

Let's look at the library dependencies of the simplest possible binary: `/bin/true`.

```
$ ldd /bin/true
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffef25f3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4635f40000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4636159000)
```

The first of these, `linux-vdso.so.1` is a *virtual dynamic shared object* which is not present on disk at all, but exported by the kernel to every program it loads. Its purpose is to make system calls more efficient.

The second line refers to `libc.so.6`. This is the C library, usually `glibc`. On Debian and related distributions, there is a `x86_64-linux-gnu` sub-directory under `/lib` to allow an arbitrary number of system architectures to share a system disk easily.

The third line refers to the dynamic linker/loader `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (name will obviously vary on different system architectures).

If the dynamic linker/loader is not available at the expected path, the system will be unable to complete the loading procedure for any binary (= executable program) that is not fully statically linked. Most binaries on modern Linux systems are not statically linked, as statically linked programs tend to take up more disk space than dynamically linked ones.

The C library is the most critical of all library files: even the simplest binaries tend to depend on it.

When the system is booting up, a standard initramfs is usually designed to handle the minimum number of tasks:

- enabling swap if necessary
- mounting the root filesystem
- optionally initiating the process to resume from a hibernation image, if hibernation (suspend-to-disk) is enabled

Since initramfs normally only cares about the root filesystem, the root filesystem must be self-contained enough that the boot process can immediately continue after switching from initramfs to real root filesystem. This means the root filesystem must contain at least the essential system libraries, executables and configuration files. Classically this has meant that the root filesystem must contain `/etc`, `/lib`, `/bin` and `/sbin` (and also `/lib64` if used by the system architecture).

It might be technically possible to build a custom initramfs file that would also mount a separate filesystem to e.g. `/lib` when transitioning to the real root filesystem, but this would introduce a lot of complications to a critical early part of the boot process. I would not recommend that.

So the answer to the question in the title is "no, you cannot (easily) move /lib to a different filesystem and have the system remain bootable."

---

Since your root filesystem is `ext4` on LVM, and the LVM volume group that contains the root filesystem has plenty of free (unassigned) capacity according to the `vgs` command, you were in excellent position to expand your root filesystem on-line.

While the system is running normally, all you needed to do was:

1. Put your cool sunglasses on  B-)
2. `sudo lvextend -L <new-size>G --resizefs /dev/mapper/Oak-root`
3. Done.

However, as you already discovered, when extending an ext2/3/4 filesystem to beyond about 100x the size it was originally created as, you need to be aware that you may encounter a limit that stops you from completing the extension on-line. If you hit this limit, the easiest workaround is to boot the system using an external live Linux media, activate the volume group (if using LVM), and run `resize2fs` on the unmounted root filesystem: this will automatically perform an "off-line" filesystem extension, which can surpass that limit and will automatically reserve enough new gdb blocks to allow the filesystem to be expanded on-line to at least 100x of the *new* size again.

The common `resize2fs` command is part of the e2fsprogs package, but there exists an alternative ext2/3 resizing toolkit: [GNU ext2resize.](http://ext2resize.sourceforge.net/) Unfortunately its development has stalled since the ext4 filesystem type was developed, but it included an additional `ext2prepare` tool that could be used off-line to pre-emptively increase the amount of gdb blocks to allow subsequent on-line filesystem expansion to very high multiples of initial size. Adding a similar functionality to `resize2fs` is on its developer's TODO list.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing the answer. While I have now moved to a different part of the self made hell that is upgrading from wheezy to bullseye all at once, This is a great answer that would have helped me quite a bit and explains the reasons and solutions well. Also it never occurred to me that things like cp/mv/mkdir or mount would be dynamically linked. It does make some sense, but is fairly surprising.